# Is non root user and Seccomp necessary on docker desktop?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-desktop, seccomp

I was reading through playwright docs and when using docker they recommend to create a separate user inside the Docker container and use the seccomp profile. And a few questions came up to mind: is this necessary (security improvement) if I am using docker desktop (since docker desktop already runs inside a VMP). How should I go to enable seccomp on the VM running docker? And finally, if I understood right this would only enable the seccomp, but the actual restrictions imposed by the seccomp would be applied on a container basis and according to the profile I pass to that container, i.e. the restrictions would be applied to that container alone. Is that correct?

Comment: Seccomp is purely a linux kernel facility to restrict syscalls that a process may make. It has nothing to do with virtual machines or whether the kernel runs on one.

Comment: @user17732522 docker desktop run on a vm running linux. As far as I can tell that linux kernel running on the vm does not have seccomp enabled, and my question is if I should enable it and how is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Seccomp is either built into the kernel or not available at all. There is no extra step to enable/disable it. Whether seccomp restrictions are used is up to the user-space process, i.e. Docker creating containers.

Comment: @user17732522 got it. That answers some of my questions. Tks